# Resample dataframe with count method for certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to resample data from a dataframe. Columns have different types of data. For one of the columns I'd like to count the rows for which the column has a value larger than 0.

A small example would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-01-15'),
                        'A': np.random.randint(5, size=15)})
df.set_index(df.Date, inplace=True)

df.resample('5D').count()
```

Counting works, but I can't find a way to insert the condition that I only want to count values larger than 0. Something like this:

```
df.resample('5D').count(df[df.A > 0])
```

However, `TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Question: How to `resample().count()` with conditions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Resampler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply.html) and `sum` of `True`s values which are processes like `1`s:

```
np.random.seed(57)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-01-15'),
                        'A': np.random.randint(5, size=15)})
df.set_index(df.Date, inplace=True)

df1 = df.resample('5D')['A'].apply(lambda x: (x > 0).sum())
print (df1)
Date
2018-01-01    2
2018-01-06    3
2018-01-11    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Or better solution is create boolean mask and with `resample` aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df['A'] > 0).resample('5D').sum().astype(int)
print (df1)

Date
2018-01-01    2
2018-01-06    3
2018-01-11    4
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Yes, it count because it sum of boolean Trues, like `s = pd.Series([True, False, True, False, True])
print (s)

print (s.sum())
`